# Webpack - How to bundle/require all files of a folder (subfolder)

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle, atom-editor

I am trying to see if there is a shorter way of running webpack bundles, and also why my loaders do not work.

Here is my code:

```
module.exports = {
context: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
entry: ['./ES6bundle.js', './jQuery.js'],
output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
}
};
// module: {
//     loaders: [{
//         test: /\.js?$/,
//         exclude: /node_modules/,
//         loader: 'babel-loader',
//         query: {
//             presets: ['env']
//         }
//     }]
// };
```

The module.exports works but when I run the loaders I get errors.

My other question is about consolidating multiple entries into one file.
The project I am working on has many JS files, and I was wondering if there was a shortcut for multiple entries. Instead of typing out multiple entries' filenames, can I grab all JS files in the same folder or have a JS file to require them all?

Let me know if this makes sense or not. I am relatively new to programming. Thanks!

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting when running the loaders?

Comment: So I fixed the loader part of my question not too long after posting. In regards to my other question, is there a way to add multiple entries with one file path or do I need to enter them manually each time?

Comment: `entry` in my experience is for distinctly separate entry points into your app - if you want a single bundle output then you should really only have one entry point which in turn requires/imports the other files using something like the commonjs format. Or do genuinely have very many distinct entry points? edit: are you doing the multi-main entry thing?

Comment: I can try the multi-main entry thing, I guess one way I could import the files into a single one for the entry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding the second part of your question:

> can I grab all JS files in the same folder or have a JS file to
>   require them all

You can have one entry file and in there you do:

```
module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    entry: ['./jQuery.js', './allJsFilesOfFolder.js'],
```

**allJsFilesOfFolder.js:**

```
require.context("../scripts/", true, /\.js$/);
```

This will bundle all scripts inside `scripts` and all its `subfolders`.

You need to install `@types/webpack-env` to have `context` at your hand.

Specify `false` if you want to bundle only the scripts in the `scripts` folder.

You can do the same with other resources like images, you only have to adapt the `regex`

Comment: `require.context("./src", true, /\.src\.js$/);`   This is what I came out with but I am getting the error "npm ERR! missing script: scripts

Comment: Try `webpack -d --display-entrypoints --progress --display-modules --display-error-details`, this will give you more information in general.
You get this error most probably, because it cannot resolve your `./src`

Comment: Btw. your regex will match only js files ending with `.src.js`.
How do you execute the `webpack` command, the error msg says: `missing script: scripts`!?

Comment: I got it to work thank you so much! One final question, is there a way to pull in multiple file types in the same directory not just .js files? I have a few .vue files and was wondering if this is possible. Thanks!

Comment: I have no experience with vue files, but as I said you can bundle not only js files, but also image files, for example the regex for image files would be: `/\.(png|ico|svg|jpg|gif)$/`. Don't forget to mark it as an answer if it helped you. Thanks.

Comment: to run my webpack command I do `npm run build`, not sure why but I am encountering errors again when I run the bundle.

Comment: @Legends I am getting error require.context is not a function. Even after installing @types/webpack-env.

Comment: @Vish Open another question on SO and create demo repo on github first, which reproduces your error.

Comment: I was able to produce desired effect only when `allJsFilesOfFolder.js` was in the path of `require.context`. That way the resulting js file contained code from all js files in the dir.

Answer (score 0):

Copy @Legends comment as answer here.

> have no experience with vue files, but as I said you can bundle not only js files, but also image files, for example the regex for image files would be: /.(png|ico|svg|jpg|gif)$/.