# Fix Class is not a constructor error when using namespace in TypeScript with WebPack

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, pixi.js, tsc

**Overview**
I'm new to using TypeScript and PIXI.js without a framework. I used to use the language/library for work where we used namespaces with the module keyword. I've been trying to replicate the setup we used as I think it looks a lot better than having loads of import statements.

**The Problem**
When I run my code in the browser, I get the following error in the windows inspector console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: MyApp.AbstractModel is not a constructor
    at Main../src/Main.ts.Main.createModel (Main.ts:16)
```

**What I've Found & Attempted Fixes**
I have read through the typescript documentation for Namespaces found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html) and [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) loads of times but cannot see where I am going wrong.

Initially I thought the issue was that not all files were being loaded by webpack but I fixed that with suggestions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48990197/webpack-how-to-bundle-require-all-files-of-a-folder-subfolder) (namely the "require.context()") and still the error persists.

I've tried importing the namespace from the main file (copied what's in Main to Game.ts, and put the following in Main.ts)

```
require.context("../src/", true, /\.ts$/);
/// <reference path="Game.ts" />

class Main {

    constructor() {
        console.log("Main.constructor()");
        new MyApp.Game();
    }

}
new Main();
```

**The Structure**
My file structure is as follows:

```
stack-overflow-example
| - .idea
| - dev
| | - dts
| | | <all .d.ts files from tsc compilation>
| | - js
| | | <all .js files and accompanying .js.map files from compiled .ts files>
| | - index.html
| - node_modules
| - src
| | - graphics
| | | - pixi-manager.ts
| | - model
| | | - AbstractModel.ts
| | - Main.ts
| | - refs.ts
| package.json
| package-lock.json
| tsconfig.json
| webpack.config.js
```

**The Code**
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>stack-overflow-example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="js/Bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Maint.ts

```
/// <reference path="refs.ts" />
require.context("../src/", true, /\.ts$/);

namespace MyApp {
    export class Main {

        public static instance: Main = new Main();
        public model: AbstractModel;

        constructor() {
            console.log("Main.constructor()");
            this.createModel();
        }

        protected createModel(): void {
            this.model = new AbstractModel();
        }

        protected addComponent(view: PIXI.DisplayObject): void {
            PixiManager.instance.stage.addChild(view);
        }

        public getModel(): AbstractModel {
            return this.model;
        }
    }
}
```

AbstractModel.ts

```
/// <reference path="../refs.ts" />
namespace MyApp {
    export class AbstractModel {

        constructor() {
            console.log("AbstractModel.constructor()");
        }

    }
}
```

refs.ts

```
/// <reference path="graphics/pixi-manager.ts" />
/// <reference path="model/AbstractModel.ts" />
/// <reference path="Main.ts" />
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-game",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "Main.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --content-base dev/ --inline --hot"
  },
  "devDependencies": {...}
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dev/js/",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ES5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "./dev/dts"
  },
  "include": ["./src/*.ts"]
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require("path");
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        namespace: "./src/Main.ts"
    },
    mode: "development",
    devtool: "source-map",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dev/js/"),
        filename: "js/Bundle.js"
    }
};
```

**The Question**
How can I fix the "MyApp.AbstractModel is not a constructor" error while keeping the namespace style rather than using modules?

All help will be really appreciated, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

First please check why `is not a constructor` error is happening: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_constructor . It seems that probably the `AbstractModel` is not defined where the error is happening.

You could check it like this:

```
        protected createModel(): void {
            console.log(typeof AbstractModel);
            this.model = new AbstractModel();
        }
```

If thats the case then you should change this question to something like: "How to load all classes from directory in TypeScript and WebPack?".

Then, the thing which you wanted to do using `require.context(...` aproach can be done as described in: [Is it possible to import modules from all files in a directory, using a wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722270/is-it-possible-to-import-modules-from-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-wildcard/57009738#57009738)

**BUT** please also read following docs :

- [How to import all modules from a directory in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40702842/how-to-import-all-modules-from-a-directory-in-typescript/40703602#40703602)
- [Typescript: export all functions in a namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168733/typescript-export-all-functions-in-a-namespace/38175062#38175062)

  - ^ [Why is "import *" bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad)
- the `In practice` part of this answer: [Is it possible to import modules from all files in a directory, using a wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722270/is-it-possible-to-import-modules-from-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-wildcard/54755847#54755847)

As you see this is considered a bad practice by some people. I also prefer to explicitly enumerate all dependencies for current file. This way you can see exactly what is used where. Also the IDE should help you with that.

Next problem is `<reference path...` vs `import` usage. First you say:

> ... as I think it looks a lot better than having loads of import statements.

But then in `refs.ts` you do:

```
/// <reference path="graphics/pixi-manager.ts" />
/// <reference path="model/AbstractModel.ts" />
/// <reference path="Main.ts" />
```

so instead of using `loads of import statements` you have `loads of reference statements` :) . The number of code lines seems the same as when you would use imports.

Additionally please see again example from doc that you linked in your question: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#multi-file-namespaces - in the `Test.ts` file there is `<reference` for each needed file :

```
/// <reference path="Validation.ts" />
/// <reference path="LettersOnlyValidator.ts" />
/// <reference path="ZipCodeValidator.ts" />

...
```

in files `LettersOnlyValidator.ts` and `ZipCodeValidator.ts` there is referenced `/// <reference path="Validation.ts" />` - but in last file they need to reference `/// <reference path="Validation.ts" />` again - so it means that "reference path approach" is not [transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation).

This means that you should better rethink this and try to use `import` (and/or `export`) where needed.

- [Typescript ///<reference path=“…”> and "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44639507/typescript-reference-path-and-uncaught-referenceerror-exports-is-not)